# Don't understand this error message

Tags: c++

```
double highestTempOfYear(Mweather data[12]){
    vector<double> temps;
    for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++){
        temps.push_back(data[i].high_temperature);
        temps.push_back(data[i].low_temperature);
    }
    return *max_element(temps.begin(),temps.end());
}

double lowestTempOfYear(MWeather data[12]){
    vector<double> temps;
    for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++){
        temps.push_back(data[i].high_temperature);
        temps.push_back(data[i].low_temperature);
    }
```

On the line of the function header, `double lowestTempOfYear(MWeather data[12])`,

> "Error: expected ',' or ';' before '{' token"

Comment: Is `lowestTempOfYear` missing your closing `}` or was that a copy/paste error?

Comment: Perhaps you'll find [Clang 3.4](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d5f6c046d2733461)'s error better.

Comment: `MWeather` != `Mweather`

Comment: The fact you don't understand the error message, what it means etc. doesn't mean it's "meaningless". C++ parsers are truly complicated, and though error messages aren't always very descriptive or appropriate, they are meaningful ! :) Remember to check everything on the line actually implied, but also the lines before (as some errors might go undetected until a certain point).

Comment: Um, error messages are not "meaningless". You have to think about the possible reasons for an error.

Comment: I'll bet that there's one more error message before that one.

Comment: @jrok MWeather was not declared in this scope

Comment: @AmberRoxanna Correct. did you see the linked message from chris, or my not-so-subtle comment about the difference between `MWeather` and `Mweather`. Does it help to remember C/C++ are case-sensitive?

Comment: @WhozCraig I fixed that, but the message in my post is still there

Comment: Did you save the file before recompiling after changing `MWeather` to `Mweather` ? [See it live here.](http://ideone.com/NX027B)

Answer (score 2):

```
double lowestTempOfYear(MWeather data[12]){
// ...

} //You missed to close the curly brace
```

Also make sure you to match up your `MWeather` is it `Mweather` ? as in comments

Comment: Whilst notable, thats not where the error is being reported. It is on the decl line (and still would be even with this closing brace).